# Remove Object from runTransactionBlock Array [Swift Firebase]

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use Firebase and `runTransactionBlock` to update an Array on a server. I previously was able to add the uid of `userToFollow` to `user`'s `Following` node using the solution found on [Synchronized Array (for likes/followers) Best Practice [Firebase Swift]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999383/synchronized-array-for-likes-followers-best-practice-firebase-swift/39006089#39006089). Now I am trying to enable unfollowing by removing the uid of `userToFollow` from `user`'s `Following node`, but despite the `runTransactionBlock` succeeding the data is not getting updated. Here is my code:

```
static func unfollow(user: FIRUser, userToUnfollow: FIRUser) {
    self.database.child("users/"+(user.uid)+"/Following").runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: FIRMutableData!) -> FIRTransactionResult in
        var value = currentData?.value as? Array<String>
        if (value == nil) {
            print("unfollow - user has never followed user ID " + userToUnfollow.uid)
            FIRTransactionResult.abort()
        } else {
            value = value!.filter() {$0 != userToUnfollow.uid}
        }
        currentData.value = value!
        return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
    }) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
        if let error = error {
            print("unfollow - update user unfollowing transaction, please try again - EXCEPTION: " + error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            print("unfollow - update user unfollowing success")
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to update the array by first sorting out the uid of `userToUnfollow` then syncing this data with Firebase. How can I get this to actually remove the node? Thanks.

Comment: Setting the value to `null` will remove the node.